# Why does Amy consider Sheldon's research better than others' when Sheldon's is the most theoretical?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

From [S04E03 – The Zazzy Substitution](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-4-episode-03-the-zazzy-substitution/) (emphasis added)

> Amy: It’s very impressive, **for theoretical work**.
>
> Sheldon: Do I detect a hint of condescension?
>
> Amy: I’m sorry, was I being too subtle? I meant compared to the
> **real-world applications** of neurobiology, theoretical physics is,
> what’s the word I’m looking for? Hmm, cute.
>
> Leonard and Howard together: Oooh!
>
> Sheldon: Are you suggesting the work of a neurobiologist like Babinski
> could ever rise to the significance of a physicist like Clarke-Maxwell
> or Dirac?
>
> Amy: I’m stating it outright. Babinski eats Dirac for breakfast and
> defecates Clarke-Maxwell.
>
> Sheldon: You take that back.
>
> Amy: Absolutely not. My colleagues and I are mapping the neurological
> substrates that subserve global information processing, which is
> required for all cognitive reasoning, including scientific inquiry,
> making my research ipso facto prior in the ordo cognoscendi. That
> means it’s better than his research, and **by extension, of course**,
> **yours.**

Sheldon's a theoretical physicist. Raj and Leonard are applied physicists. Howard is an engineer. If Amy's saying neurobiology is better for having more real world applications / being more practical / whatever, then how is Amy's research better than the others' research from that (see the 'by extension') Amy's research is better than Sheldon's? I think it should be the converse: If Amy's research is better than theirs, then Amy's research is better than Sheldon's.

**Edit 1:**

It's like this:

My assumptions are

1. Amy thinks Amy's research is better than Sheldon's.
2. Amy thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research.

Then...

3. By (1) and (2), Amy thinks Amy's research is better than the others'.

I don't believe I'm mistaken for (1) and (3). I'm questioning (2). I think that not only should (2) be false but also should Amy think the exact opposite: the others' research is better than Sheldon's.

**Edit 2:**

Dale M comments:

> "Amy thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research." - Justify. There is no support for this in the dialogue.

My response:

This is exactly I was wondering. The key phrase here is 'by extension'. Okay fine **I'll just say explicitly what I was trying to get at. (I was avoiding this to not be judgemental if I'm right and stupid if I'm wrong.)**

4. I know Sheldon thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research. So I was wondering: Maybe the series **is trying to portray Amy as a female version Sheldon and so MISTAKENLY copied this opinion Sheldon has to Amy**. This is what Paul D. Waite says in comments:

> Yup, me too. I’m saying Amy thinks Sheldon’s research is better than the other guy’s research for the same reason she thinks hers is better than Sheldon’s: *ordo cognoscendi*

See? But it's a different 'ordo cognoscendi'... I think. Here's what I think:

- 4.1. Sheldon would think Sheldon's research is prior to not only Amy's but also the others' in the ordo cognoscendi *because Sheldon's work is theoretical* under some idea 'theoretical is prior to practical.'
- 4.2. Amy thinks Amy's research is prior to Sheldon's in the ordo cognoscendi *because Amy's work is applied* under some idea 'practical is prior to theoretical.'
- 4.3. Under the idea 'practical is prior to theoretical', there's no way Amy would agree with Sheldon in (4.1).
- 4.4 **The only way out I see for Amy here is that maybe Amy's reason in (4.2) is not 'practical is prior to theoretical.'** Maybe Amy does think Sheldon's research is prior to the others' in the ordo cognoscendi because Sheldon's work is theoretical and indeed 'theoretical is prior to practical', albeit Amy has an exception to this idea: **Amy somehow bypasses this usual idea** because of the specific nature of Amy's research which is:

> I will be able to map and reproduce your thought processes in deriving a grand unified theory, and therefore, subsume your conclusions under my paradigm.

Comment: Amy's research is better because she's figuring out how thinking works, which explains theoretical physics (because theoretical physics is made of thinking), which explains applied physics. [_Ordo cognoscendi_, bitches](https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/2n623b/comment/cmasqb1/?context=3).

Comment: I don't see why you bring Raj, Leonard, and Howard into the mix, as Amy herself doesn't do so. She merely states Sheldon's research is very impressive, but his field is not as impressive as that of neurobiology, because it's theoretical and has (little to) no real-world applications. Maybe engineering and applied physics fall short on other ways.

Comment: @Joachim 'I don't see why you bring Raj, Leonard, and Howard into the mix, as Amy herself doesn't do so.' - serious? I put it in bold ' That means it’s better than his research, and by extension, of course, yours.' - who else is Amy talking to?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I understand why Amy thinks Amy's research is better than Sheldon's research.  It's like this: My assumptions are 1 - Amy thinks Amy's research is better than Sheldon's 2 - Amy thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research. 3 - By (1) and (2), Amy thinks Amy's research is better than the others'. I don't believe I'm mistaken for (1) and (3). I'm questioning (2).

Comment: @BCLC Yup, me too. I’m saying Amy thinks Sheldon’s research is better than the other guy’s research for the same reason she thinks hers is better than Sheldon’s: _ordo cognoscendi_

Comment: Are you getting Raj, Leonard, and Howard confused with Dirac and Clarke-Maxwell in Amy’s comments? Seems like she’s saying her field is superior to the field of the latter two (not the former three), and therefore superior to Sheldon’s.

Comment: Side note: Einstein’s completely theoretical work on general relativity provided a critical underpinning for GPS. So while much theoretical physics does not at this time have an application, it’s not necessarily less applicable just because it’s theoretical.

Comment: She is talking to Sheldon. With "his" she is referring back to "Clarke-Maxwell or Dirac", as she mentioned them already. Leonard and Howard are only part of this scene through reacting to Amy and Sheldon's argument (saying "oooh"): this is not in any way about them.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanks a lot! I edited my post.

Comment: "his research" refers to Babinksi

Comment: @Yorik Oh thanks i guess that might make sense... so if 'his research' refers to sheldon then...?

Answer (score 2):

### She doesn't consider it better than *others*; she considers it worse than *hers*

> ... compared to the real-world applications of neurobiology, theoretical physics is, what’s the word I’m looking for? Hmm, cute.

The comparison is between neurobiology and theoretical physics: she isn't commenting on applied physics or engineering.

She possibly would consider her work superior to the others but she's not making that argument here.

Comment: (1/2) 'she isn't commenting on applied physics or engineering (...) not making that argument here.' - What? What does ' That means it’s better than his research, and by extension, of course, yours.' mean? Who is Amy talking to? It's like this: My assumptions are 1 - Amy thinks Amy's research is better than Sheldon's 2 - Amy thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research. 3 - By (1) and (2), Amy thinks Amy's research is better than the others'. I don't believe I'm mistaken for (1) and (3). I'm questioning (2).

Comment: (2/2) Sheldon often considers Sheldon's research to be better than the others'. But I think Amy should not only disagree but also think think the opposite: The others are applied physicists and engineers. Since the others' research have more real world applications than Sheldon's, Amy should ostensibly think the exact opposite of (2). What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: 'She doesn't consider it better than others; she considers it better than hers' - take off pronouns please. Do you mean 'Amy doesn't consider Sheldon's research better than others' research; Amy considers the others' research better than Amy's research' ? That's a different 'it', so there's ambiguity. I don't think both of the 'it' 's can refer to Amy's research, Sheldon's research or the others' research.

Comment: "Amy thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research." - Justify. There is no support for this in the dialogue.

Comment: Exactly Dale M! That's what I was wondering. The key phrase here is 'by extension'. I know Sheldon thinks Sheldon's research is better than the others' research. So I was wondering maybe the series is trying to portray Amy as a female Sheldon and so copied this opinion Sheldon has to Amy and then they made a mistake. (Edited post just now.)